# invoke command on all those servers to see which admin accounts are active on each server

Tags: powershell

I have  been fetching  both direct members and groups inside local administrators group in our remote machines. I want to get an output like below.

Also , if there are GROUP members  inside local admin group then I want to organize only GROUP members like below.

`MACHINE01,User01,TRUE,GROUP01;GROUP02`

output:

```
"Computername","Members"
"MACHINE01","contoso\User01 contoso\User02 contoso\GROUP01 contoso\GROUP02
```

desired output:

```
Computername,Direct Members,Account Status,Group Members
MACHINE01,User01,TRUE,GROUP01;GROUP02
MACHINE01,User02,FALSE  
MACHINE02,User05,TRUE,GROUP04;GROUP05;GROUP12
MACHINE02,User08,FALSE
MACHINE02,User12,FALSE  
MACHINE44,User07,TRUE
```

script :

```
$server_list = @()
Import-Csv C:\temp\server3.csv | ForEach-Object {$server_list += $_.name}

invoke-command {
    $members = net localgroup administrators | 
     where {$_ -AND $_ -notmatch "command completed successfully"} | 
     select -skip 4
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
     Computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
     Members=$members
     }
    } -computer $server_list -HideComputerName | Select * -ExcludeProperty RunspaceID, PSComputerName, PSShowComputerName | Export-CSV c:\temp\local_admins2.csv -NoTypeInformation


Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=test,DC=local" | select 
name | Export-Csv C:\data\servers3.csv
```

---

Output:

```
"ComputerName","Direct Members","Account Status","Group Members"
"machine01","user01","OK",""
"machine01","user02","Degraded",""
"machine02","user03","OK",""
"machine02","user04","Degraded",""
```

LASTLY UPDATE OUTPUT WMI:

```
ComputerName Direct Members Account Status Group Members          
------------ -------------- -------------- -------------          
**MACHINE01    Administrator  Degraded       Domain Admins;IT-Admins**
MACHINE01    Theo           OK                                    
MACHINE01    LocalAdmin     OK
**MACHINE02    Administrator  Degraded       DBA Admins;Software-Admins**
MACHINE02    Theo           OK                                    
MACHINE02    LocalAdmin     OK
```

Comment: This is the **same** output I have showed you (and is what you asked for). Now your latest comment says you do not get group names, but then.. how come I get the results from **all three alternatives** I posted? My suggestion would be to stop using ancient OS-es and at the very least upgrade the .net framework on machines that can handle it.

Comment: I am assuming , I have found issue. Now , I have tested it on machine installed my powershell 5.1.  if I use  `$server_list = "hostname01"` instead of  `$server_list = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\server3.csv').name` then  I can  get group names inside output.  But if I use `$server_list = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\server3.csv').name` on remote machine (powershell 5.1)  then I can't get group names inside output.

Comment: So I mean when  I get administrator group members on remote computer then I can't get group names.  But its works on itself computer.

Comment: Then check your CSV file. [1] It probably doesn't have a header `name` or [2] it doesn't use the comma as delimiter but some other character. In case of [1]: Use `Get-Content` if the file is just a list of server names each on a new line. In case of [2] Add parameter `-Delimiter` to the Import-Csv command, followed by the character you **DO** use in the file. Nothing to do with my code.

Comment: :( still same issue anyway I'll deal it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

`net localgroup` does not output anything that differentiates between users or groups, so if possible, use
`Get-LocalGroupMember` and `Get-LocalUser`:

```
$server_list = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\server3.csv').name

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server_list -ScriptBlock {
    $members = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"
    $groups  = $members | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group'} | ForEach-Object {($_.Name -split '\\')[-1]}
    $users   = @($members | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'User'})
    if ($users.Count) {
        # now loop over the user objects
        $users | ForEach-Object {
            $name = ($_.Name -split '\\')[-1]
            $user = if ($_.PrincipalSource -eq 'Local') {
                        Get-LocalUser -Name $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    }
                    else {
                        Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$name'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                    }

            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'ComputerName'   = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                'Direct Members' = $name
                'Account Status' = $user.Enabled
                'Group Members'  = $groups -join ';'
            }
            # clear the $goups here because you only want to list them once per server
            $groups = $null
        }
    }
    else {
        # no users, just groups
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'ComputerName'   = $env:COMPUTERNAME
            'Direct Members' = $null
            'Account Status' = $null
            'Group Members'  = $groups -join ';'
        }
    }
} | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PSComputerName, RunspaceId

$result | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\local_admins2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

If module [Microsoft.Powershell.LocalAccounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/?view=powershell-5.1) is not available to you, you can experiment with module [localaccount](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/localaccount/1.6), but I have no experience with that..

---

I don't have that old OSes, so you'll have to test this.
Below uses WMI to query the servers for the group memberships:

```
$server_list = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\server3.csv').name

$result = foreach ($server in $server_list) {
    $query   = "Associators of {Win32_Group.Domain='$server',Name='Administrators'} where Role=GroupComponent"
    $members = Get-WmiObject -Query $query -ComputerName $server | 
               Where-Object { $_.__CLASS -match '(User|Group)' } |
               Select-Object Name, Caption, 
                             @{Name = 'ObjectClass'; Expression = {$matches[1]}},
                             @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.__SERVER}},
                             Status, LocalAccount, SID, Domain

    $groups = @($members | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group'})
    $users  = @($members | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'User'})
    if ($users.Count) {
        # now loop over the user objects
        $users | ForEach-Object {
            # output an object
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                'ComputerName'   = $_.ComputerName
                'Direct Members' = $_.Name
                'Account Status' = $_.Status
                'Group Members'  = ($groups.Name | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ';'
            }
            # clear the $groups here because you only want to list them once per server
            $groups = $null
        }
    }
    elseif ($groups.Count) {
        # no users, just groups
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'ComputerName'   = $groups[0].ComputerName
            'Direct Members' = $null
            'Account Status' = $null
            'Group Members'  = ($groups.Name | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ';'
        }
    }
} 

$result | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\local_admins2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Another alternbative is to use `[ADSI]`:

```
$server_list = (Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\server3.csv').name

$group   = 'Administrators'
$members = foreach ($server in $server_list) {
    try {
        ([ADSI]"WinNT://$server/$group,group").psbase.Invoke('Members') | ForEach-Object {
            # test if local or domain
            $ADSPath = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("ADSPath", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
            $local   = ($ADSPath -like 'WinNT://*')
            # get the object name
            $name = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
            # get object class
            $class = $_.GetType().InvokeMember('Class', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
            if ($class -eq 'User') {
                if ($local) {
                    $flag = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("userflags", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)
                    $enabled = !($flag -band 2)  # ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE
                }
                else {
                    $enabled = (Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$name'" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Enabled
                }
            }
            else { $enabled = $null }

            [PSCustomObject] @{
                ComputerName = $server.ToUpper()
                Group        = $group
                Name         = $name
                ObjectClass  = $class
                Enabled      = $enabled
            }
        }
    } 
    catch {
        Write-Warning $_
    }
}   

$groups = @($members | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'Group'})
$users  = @($members | Where-Object {$_.ObjectClass -eq 'User'})
$result = if ($users.Count) {
    # now loop over the user objects
    $users | ForEach-Object {
        # output an object
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'ComputerName'   = $_.ComputerName
            'Direct Members' = $_.Name
            'Account Status' = $_.Enabled
            'Group Members'  = ($groups.Name | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ';'
        }
        # clear the $groups here because you only want to list them once per server
        $groups = $null
    }
}
elseif ($groups.Count) {
    # no users, just groups
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerName'   = $_.ComputerName
        'Direct Members' = $null
        'Account Status' = $null
        'Group Members'  = ($groups.Name | Sort-Object -Unique) -join ';'
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\temp\local_admins2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Output from the above when testing**

Result using `Get-LocalGroupMember`:

```
ComputerName Direct Members Account Status Group Members          
------------ -------------- -------------- -------------          
MACHINE01    Administrator           False Domain Admins;IT-Admins
MACHINE01    LocalAdmin               True                        
MACHINE01    Theo                     True
```

Result using `WMI`:

```
ComputerName Direct Members Account Status Group Members          
------------ -------------- -------------- -------------          
MACHINE01    Administrator  Degraded       Domain Admins;IT-Admins
MACHINE01    Theo           OK                                    
MACHINE01    LocalAdmin     OK
```

Result using `ADSI`:

```
ComputerName Direct Members Account Status Group Members          
------------ -------------- -------------- -------------          
MACHINE01    Administrator           False Domain Admins;IT-Admins
MACHINE01    Theo                     True                        
MACHINE01    LocalAdmin               True
```

Comment: Thanks but I have older OSes (powershell 3.0 or 4.0). how can I get this output?

Comment: So I mean , its not working such as `Get-LocalGroupMember` and `Get-ADUser` cmdlet on remote systems. Because , its not installed on these machines.  Due to that , I was using `net local group` how can we write alternative script instead of `invoke` command ?

Comment: thanks but I am not getting members of the security group inside local administrator group.  I can see just direct members .

Comment: Still same issue  I am not getting members of the security group inside local administrator group

Comment: @Arbelac I don't understand.. That is **exactly** what you asked for _" if there are GROUP members inside local admin group then I want to organize only GROUP members"_. Also, your desired output shows you do not want to recurse nested groups.

Comment: Sorry , I mean , there is no any group names inside output. To more understand,  I have update my question. (sample output) empty inside `group members` column

Comment: is there any comment ?

Comment: @Arbelac I have added test results where you can see that for me the code is working

Comment: ok thanks your help.  Lastly , I want to get group members for each machine inside above my message.   I have updated my question.  `LASTLY UPDATE OUTPUT WMI:`

Comment: btw  , `$members = Get-WmiObject -Query $query -ComputerName $server | 
               Where-Object { $_.__CLASS -match '(User|Group)' } |
               Select-Object Name, Caption, 
                             @{Name = 'ObjectClass'; Expression = {$matches[1]}},
                             @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$_.__SERVER}},
                             Status, LocalAccount, SID, Domain`                                            
      does not return group names.